# Polling online printer Queue via Android background service Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, okhttp, polling

I'm having issues with trying to poll a print queue which is hosted online

Essentially the point of the print queue is that when you call the url address if there is an item in the queue it returns it, if not it returns nothing i.e. timeout
The print queue is emptied by 1 on each call

-- Removed --

** Edit ** Tested this code actually works if the app is open and in the background, but not when the app is closed. I would ideally like to cover that

Alternate solutions welcome here is my code:

**Printer Service**

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        mRunning = true
        Thread{
            while(mRunning){
                Thread.sleep(30000)
                val response = transmit
                    .sendRequestManual("printerURL")
                if (response != null){
                    val openData = response.getElementsByTagName("printdata")
                    if(openData.length > 0){
                        for (socket in sockets) {
                            /* Bluetooth Printers */
                            write(openData.item(0).textContent, socket)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start()
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

where mRunning is set to false if the service is destroyed

**Transmit**

```
fun sendRequestManual(sendURL: String): Document?{
        /* create the XML form to be sent */
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val blockingQueue: BlockingQueue<Document> = ArrayBlockingQueue(1)


        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(sendURL)
            .get()
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException){
                /* onFailure is called each time */
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful){

                } else {
                    responseXML = response.body?.string()
                    blockingQueue.add(parseStringXMLDoc(responseXML!!))
                }
            }
        })
        return blockingQueue.poll(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
       <service
            android:name=".services.PrintService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>My code was not polling correctly, still seeking answer for polling on app close</s>

<s>Increased blocking queue time to 90 seconds</s>

So I have solved this issue, to correctly poll a server using okHTTP we need to set the response and connection time via the builder

```
var client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(90,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```

Essentially when the request is made the app will try to connect for up to 90 seconds, if a connection is made the server has 15 seconds to send it's data.

I removed

```
Thread.sleep(30000)
```

because it was causing a gap in the polling, making me think it wasn't working.

I increased

```
blockingQueue.poll(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

to 90 seconds to match the server connection time, the blocking queue will stop waiting as soon as data is received

So Essentially whenever a request is made the server has 90 seconds to connect, if not the app sends a new request.
If the server does respond, after processing the result, a new request is made and sent, which is perfect for this intended purpose (reading off a printer queue)